# Sending TMemoryStream as mail attachment

Tags: delphi, stream, email-attachments, indy, delphi-10-seattle

I am exporting a FastReport as PDFFile using TfrxPDFExport. I made a function that returns me a PDF as IStream:

```
Function TPDFReport.GetAsFile (): IStream;
var
  MStream: TMemoryStream;
Begin
  MStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    With formReport.Create (NIL) do begin
      frxPDFExport.Stream := MStream;
      frxReport.PrepareReport;
      frxReport.Export(frxPDFExport);
    end;
    Result := TStreamAdapter.Create(MStream) as IStream;
  finally

  end;
End;
```

Afterwards in a different unit I execute this function, get an IStream and load it into a TMemoryStream:

```
  PDFOleStream := TOleStream.Create(PDFReport.GetAsFile ());
  PDFMemoryStream.LoadFromStream(PDFOleStream);
```

Now I got the MemoryStream, but I don't really know the next step. I searched through web and found out that's not possible to send a Stream as a mail attachment with Indy. So I think, it's better to save a TMemoryStream as a temp file and then send it as an attachment. But as soon as I execute

```
PDFMemoryStream.SaveToFile('c:\\PDFExp.pdf');
```

I get an access violation. What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, use TIdAttachmentMemory?

Comment: Why are you converting the `TMemoryStream` to `IStream`, just to copy it to another `TMemoryStream`? Why not return and use the original `TMemoryStream` as-is instead? Also, you are leaking the `formReport`. And the only way you can get an Access Violation on `PDFMemoryStream.SaveToFile()` is if `PDFMemoryStream` is invalid. Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly how you create and use `PDFMemoryStream`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to save the `TMemoryStream` to a file just to attach it to an email. Indy's `TIdMessage` component is flexible in the types of data you can attach to it.

For instance, Indy has a `TIdAttachmentMemory` class you can use, eg:

```pascal
uses
 ..., IdAttachmentMemory;

var
  Attach: TIdAttachmentMemory;
begin
  ...

  Attach := TIdAttachmentMemory.Create(IdMessage1, PDFMemoryStream); // alternatively, use PDFOleStream instead...
  Attach.FileName := 'report.pdf';
  // set other properties as needed...

  // send the email...

  ...
end;
```

Note that `TIdAttachmentMemory` uses its own internal `TMemoryStream` and will copy the source `TStream`'s data into that internal stream. If you want to avoid that copy and send your own `TStream` as-is, you can derive your own class from `TIdAttachment` for that, eg:

```pascal
uses
  Classes, IdAttachment, IdMessageParts, IdGlobal;

type
  TIdAttachmentStream = class(TIdAttachment)
  protected
    FDataStream: TStream;
    FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition: TIdStreamSize;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TIdMessageParts; Stream: TStream); reintroduce;
    property DataStream: TStream read FDataStream;
    function OpenLoadStream: TStream; override;
    procedure CloseLoadStream; override;
    procedure FinishTempStream; override;
    function PrepareTempStream: TStream; override;
  end;

constructor TIdAttachmentStream.Create(Collection: TIdMessageParts; Stream: TStream);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FDataStream := Stream;
end;

procedure TIdAttachmentStream.CloseLoadStream;
begin
  DataStream.Position := FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition;
end;

function TIdAttachmentStream.OpenLoadStream: TStream;
begin
  FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition := DataStream.Position;
  DataStream.Position := 0;
  Result := DataStream;
end;

procedure TIdAttachmentStream.FinishTempStream;
begin
  DataStream.Position := 0;
end;

function TIdAttachmentStream.PrepareTempStream: TStream;
begin
  DataStream.Size := 0;
  Result := DataStream;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  Attach: TIdAttachmentStream;
begin
  ...

  Attach := TIdAttachmentStream.Create(IdMessage1, PDFMemoryStream); // alternatively, use PDFOleStream instead...
  Attach.FileName := 'report.pdf';
  // set other properties as needed...

  // send the email...

  ...
end;
```

Or, you can write a class to send the original `IStream` directly, eg:

```pascal
uses
  Classes, IdAttachment, IdMessageParts, IdGlobal;

type
  TIdAttachmentIStream = class(TIdAttachment)
  protected
    FDataStream: TStream;
    FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition: TIdStreamSize;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TIdMessageParts; Stream: IStream); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property DataStream: TStream read FDataStream;
    function OpenLoadStream: TStream; override;
    procedure CloseLoadStream; override;
    procedure FinishTempStream; override;
    function PrepareTempStream: TStream; override;
  end;

constructor TIdAttachmentIStream.Create(Collection: TIdMessageParts; Stream: IStream);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FDataStream := TOleStream.Create(Stream);
end;

destructor TIdAttachmentIStream.Destroy;
begin
  FDataStream.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TIdAttachmentIStream.CloseLoadStream;
begin
  DataStream.Position := FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition;
end;

function TIdAttachmentIStream.OpenLoadStream: TStream;
begin
  FDataStreamBeforeLoadPosition := DataStream.Position;
  DataStream.Position := 0;
  Result := DataStream;
end;

procedure TIdAttachmentIStream.FinishTempStream;
begin
  DataStream.Position := 0;
end;

function TIdAttachmentIStream.PrepareTempStream: TStream;
begin
  DataStream.Size := 0;
  Result := DataStream;
end;
```

```pascal
var
  Attach: TIdAttachmentIStream;
begin
  ...

  Attach := TIdAttachmentIStream.Create(IdMessage1, PDFReport.GetAsFile());
  Attach.FileName := 'report.pdf';
  // set other properties as needed...

  // send the email...

  ...
end;
```